# How to get idle time

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a report of chats handled with start and end time of chat and user who handled the chat. I want to find out total break time during the shift. They can handled one or more chats at a time, first shift starts at 9 PM and last shift logs out at 11 AM. Please see the sample data and manual calculation done for example. Let me know if you need any further details.

[image: sample data and manual calculation]

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  As a Q&A site, it relies on the structure of questions containing all of the question information, answers being reserved for solutions, and comments providing for clarification.  You've posted several answers that were feedback on another answer (comments) rather than a solution.  One was already deleted and the other likely will be soon.  It could be that you were unable to post comments on Rajesh S's answer because you created a second user account (which also means that Rajesh may be unaware of your posts).  (cont'd)

Comment: You can edit your own posts, comment within your own thread, and accept an answer, but it must be done under the user account that was used to create the question.  To get back on track, see this link to get your two accounts merged: https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts.  (cont'd)

Comment: All that said, please be aware that the site isn't intended as a free coding service, but people will help you solve specific problems that you encounter when attempting to do it yourself.  Posting a coding task isn't well-received, which likely explains the downvote.  You will get a better response if you show your own formulas, explain better how you derive idle time, and describe the specific problem that's hanging you up.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in Cell `J86` to get Chat Time:

  `=TEXT(I86-H86,"[H]:mm:ss")`

*Fill it down.*

- Enter this Formula to get Break in Cell `K86` & 
  fill it down.

`=IF(H86<I85,"00:00",TEXT(H86-I85,"[H]:mm:ss"))`

**N.B.**

- `[H]:mm:ss` is to evaluate Time as `24 
  Hrs` Time Format.
- *Adjust cell references in the Formula as 
  needed.*